# What is Islam's position on consuming meat of hybrid animals?

Tags: halal-haram, food, meat

There have been several advances in the field of genetics, and we now have hybrid animals, animals that are part human since they have human chromosomes in them.

http://www.nbcnews.com/id/7681252/ns/health-cloning_and_stem_cells/t/scientists-create-animals-are-part-human/

https://www.minds.com/blog/view/315466343296012288/the-era-of-chimeras-scientists-fearlessly-create-bizarre-humananimal-hybrids

Islam's position on cloning is very clear: it is haraam because it is playing with Allah's creation. The ethics of cloning could very well be on par with the Nazis' experiments on human subjects.

Unfortunately, such cloning experiments may leave all of us affected since I can well see a time when natural farm animals are eventually displaced with these human-animal clones. We now have genetically doctored cows that give milk very similar to human milk, and mice with part-human brains and consequently better problem-solving abilities.

My question is: what is Islam's position on the consumption of the meat of such farm animals, like GMO cattle and sheep?

Answer (score 3):

That is a great question and here is what I know. It makes sense to me therefore I share it here.

I believe the world is now advancing and we see more and more of man's interference in Allah's natural produce. I will not debate whether that is right or wrong as it does not help your question. So we'll just accept that it is what it is.

Scientifically speaking, as far as I am aware Quran does not explicitly refer to any sort of mutation. At best, the Quran does dictate that as Muslims we eat only animals that are not diseased. Mutation may be classified as a disease. Mutation can also be further classified in two forms I believe one that is Natural Mutation and the other one which is Synthetic Mutation. Evolution is, for me, a form of natural mutation. (There is a further debate here as to what causes evolution but I'll leave it for now). GE and GM for me are forms of Synthetic Mutation where wo/man has harmed the animal in some way.
Logically, I think Allah would probably not agree with the synthetic form of mutation but I am just a man and Allah knows best.

From a more political point of view, I believe, there has been no fatwa issued by any respected scholars regarding this. So until there is one or some proper research is conducted by one of the Islamic Institutes, we probably need to stay away from GE and GM produce.

I hope that helps.